# Horizontal rule below the image, except when it is the last item on the page

Tags: graphics, rules

I am using the following setup to get a horizontal line below the images in my document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myfigformat}{#1#2#3{\color{mygray}\hrulefill}}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myfigformat}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]  
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \caption{The caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{figure}[ht]  
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \caption{The caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5-7]

\begin{figure}[ht]  
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \caption{The caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How do I ensure there is no horizontal line below the image when it is the last item on the page? In the example given here, there should be no line below figure 3.

Comment: What do you mean with "last item"? If no text follows on that page? Note that the `figure` environment is a floating environment by default that will be placed by LaTeX at the top or bottom of a page if possible. So, I don't fully understand what you mean. Could you maybe explain a bit more what you would like to do exactly? Maybe add an example of a page where the line should not show and another one where it should show.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have modified the MWE to add an example of a page where the line should not show and another one where it should show.

Comment: The problem here is that TeX probably doesn't know anything about what follows when it typesets the figure including the line. Additionally, as I said, a `figure` is a float by default which is subject to a very specific positioning algorithm. So, I fear a solution for this is far from trivial. I would probably just create custom environments  (e.g. the same name with and without star) and manually tell TeX where not to print the line.